# azure cosmodb '=' in connection string fails in mongoose.connect(...)

Tags: mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

```
MongoError: database name must be a string
```

Nodejs script:

```
// Azure tells me to use mongodb://mydb:LONG-STRING-ENDING-WITH==@mydb.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true
// I change the = to %3D - I've confirmed this is the correct escaping
readonly serverConnection = 'mongodb://mydb:LONG-STRING-ENDING-WITH%3D%3D@mydb.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true');

...
const mongoDB = await mongoose.connect(
    this.serverConnection,
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
      reconnectInterval: 1000
    }
  );
```

If I remove the `==` or `%3D%3D`, or change to something else (eg. XX) then the error is the expected:

```
{ MongoError: Authentication Failed
```

So it isn't the length of the string and must be the ==.

Why is this happening?  What can one do to get around this?

Comment: I got the same problem... I copy the connection string explicit for node from azure portal and it does not work. I hope someone can explain why this happen!

Answer (score 1):

I found part of the answer.  Remove the:

```
useNewUrlParser: true
```

And ignore the warning.  For now.  It tells you that this solution won't work sometime in the future.

```
DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
```

I'd appreciate if anyone can extend this answer with details on how to use the new parser and `==` in connection strings.  And also it would be nice to know why `==` or an escaped version is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good answer, where you do not have to relinquish the new url parser. You have to add your database name at the end of the connection string like this:

```
mongodb://<connectionstring/url>:port/<DATABASENAME>?ssl=True
```

In my opinion, this is a clean solution. I hope I could help